# Functional test for scoped controller can't find the right route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `routes.rb` is :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, path: "/", constraint: { subdomain: "api" }, defaults: { format: :json } do 
    scope module: :v1 do 
      resources :users, only: [:show]

    end
  end
end
```

My `users_controller.rb` is :

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

My test is :

```
require 'test_helper'
class Api::V1::UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test '#show displays the specific user' do 
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    get :show, id: @user.id, format: :json
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Why does this test give the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/users", :format=>:json, :id=>1}
```

Comment: What do you get with `rake routes`?

Comment: `api_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json, :constraint=>{:subdomain=>"api"}}`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the constraint to the test:

```
get :show, id: @user.id, format: :json, :constraint=>{:subdomain=>"api"}
```